# Perl first pair match?

Tags: perl

I have data like these:

```
a{b}cde
a{b}c{d}e
```

I want to spilt the string into three parts:

1. string before first {} pair
2. string in first {} pair
3. rest

here is my code:

```
if(/(.*){(.*)}(.*)/){
    print "$1\t$2\t$3\n";  # ===> a{b}c   d       e
}
```

but it's not work for `a{b}c{d}e`

I want `a   b    c{d}e` instead of `a{b}c   d       e`

Comment: So by "first pair" you mean the "last pair"?

Comment: no, the first : his example show a (before first pair) and b (inside first pair) and c{d}e (after first pair)

Comment: You should really escape the bare `{` and `}`. Use either `\{` or `[{]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making .* non-greedy (.*?) will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if($line =~ m/(.*?){(.*?)}(.*)/){
    print "$1\t$2\t$3\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
a{b}cde
a{b}c{d}e
```

Answer (score 1):

While non-greedy matches work in this case, I would advocate instead using a negated character class.  This states more explicitly that you want a series of non-`}` characters, rather than the shortest possible sequence of any character at all which is followed by a `}`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  say "$1\t$2\t$3" if /^([^{]*){([^}]*)}(.*)/;
} 

__DATA__
a{b}cde
a{b}c{d}e
```

Comment: Dave, is the negated character class faster?

Comment: @MauritzHansen: In principle, it _can_ be because it seriously reduces (or, in this case, completely eliminates) the possibility that the regex engine might need to backtrack in order to find the correct match. In practice, the Perl regex engine is optimized pretty heavily, so I don't think there should be a noticeable performance difference in non-pathological cases.